# WinRT - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have to make a MetroApp Frontend in C#.

I have an OverviewPage where i got a `GridView` with a Preview of the Detail Page.
I discribed it more detailed and with screenshot in the following thread:
[WinRT XamlControl Preview Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822211/winrt-xamlcontrol-preview-image)

I get the Content-Panel which i display in the DetailPage from an external library.

Because i want a Preview of the DetailPage in my OverviewItems i have to show the same `Panel` in my `GridView Items`.

When i click on an `Item` it navigates me to the DetailPage and i get the following error when i try to add the Panel to my DetailPage: Value does not fall within the expected range.

I think this is because i got already a Panel with equal names in my VisualTree?! Is this assumption right? The Panel contains a Canvas with some xaml elements and onclick-Event-triggers on it btw.

What can i do to fix this bug? I dont know how to continue.. :/

If you need more information - just ask please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the same instance of an element in multiple places in the app, so if an instance is already somewhere in the visual tree - you can't also add it elsewhere. I don't think duplicate names are a problem unless they are in the same name scope and if they were you would probably fail at build time.